# Cannot assign to read only property 'closed' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been cracking my head on this for a few days now, but I can't find the reason why this is happening.

So I'm getting the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'closed' of object '[object Object]'

[image]

So as you can see, it happens in the civilliability-step3.component.ts at the sendProposal function:

`civilliability-step3.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-civilliability-step3',
  templateUrl: './civilliability-step3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./civilliability-step3.component.scss']
})
export class CivilliabilityStep3Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter<CivilLiabilityRequestType>();
  @Output() onCloseForm = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() model: CivilLiabilityRequestType;

  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  private closedProposalSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();

    if (this.model !== undefined && this.model.details.closed) {
      disableFormGroup(this.formGroup);
    }

    this.closedProposalSub = this.store
      .select(ProposalsState.closedProposalResult)
      .subscribe(val => {
        if (val !== undefined) {
          this.modelChange.emit(val);
          this.onCloseForm.emit();
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.closedProposalSub && !this.closedProposalSub.closed) {
      this.closedProposalSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.store.dispatch(new ResetClosedProposalResult());
  }  

  sendProposal() {
    this.model.details.closed = true;
    this.store.dispatch(new CloseProposal(this.model));
  }

  closeForm() {
    disableFormGroup(this.formGroup);
  }

  private buildForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }
}
```

Useage of the component:

`civilliability-detail.component.html`

```
<app-civilliability-step3
          (onCloseForm)="step1.closeForm(); step2.closeForm(); step3.closeForm()"
          [(model)]="model"
          #step3></app-civilliability-step3>
```

I've tried assigning the true value differently, because I figured maybe I can't add it directly to the model, which is an `Input`. But that didn't help either.

```
  sendProposal() {
    const detailsModel = this.model.details;
    detailsModel.closed = true; // <-- same error
    this.model.details = detailsModel;

    const tmpModel = this.model;
    tmpModel.details.closed = true; // <-- same error
    this.model = tmpModel;

    // this.model.details.closed = true;
    this.store.dispatch(new CloseProposal(this.model));
  }
```

**UPDATE 1:** Added CivilLiabilityRequestType

```
export interface CivilLiabilityRequestType extends IRequestData {
  details: CivilLiabilityDetailsModel;
  questionnaire: CivilLiabilityQuestionnaireModel;
  comments: CivilLiabilityCommentsModel;
}

export class CivilLiabilityDetailsModel {
  baseReqId: number;

  startDate: string;
  branch: NamedResource;
  fractioning: NamedResource;
  closed: boolean;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Show origin of this.model:

`civilliability-detail.component.ts`

```
export class CivilliabilityProposalDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() model: CivilLiabilityRequestType;
  @Input() tab: Tab;
  @Input() tabs: Tab[] = [];
  @Input() selectedTabIndex;
  @Input() idx: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.model = getEmptyCivilLiabilityRequest();
  }
}
```

`detail.component.html`

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let idx = index">
...
<app-civilliability-proposal-detail
  [model]="tab.tabData.data"
  [tab]="tab"
  [tabs]="tabs"
  [selectedTabIndex]="selectedTabIndex"
  [idx]="idx"
>
</app-civilliability-proposal-detail>
...
</mat-tab>
```

`detail.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public tabs: Tab[] = [];
  public selectedTabIndex = 0;
  public quote?: QuoteData;
  public quoteModel: QuoteData;
  public originalModel: any[];
  public readonly = false;
  @Input() public requestType;

  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const snapshot = this.activeRoute.snapshot;

    this.originalModel = snapshot.data['model'];
    if (this.originalModel) {
      this.tabs = this.createTabsFromQuoteModel(this.originalModel);
    }
  }

  private createTabsFromQuoteModel(model: any): Tab[] {
    let tabs: Tab[] = [];

    for (const key of Object.keys(model)) {
      const element = model[key];
      let type: RequestTypes;
      let proposalData: IRequestData = {};

      if (key === 'civilLiability') {
        type = RequestTypes.CivilLiability;
        proposalData.type = RequestTypes.CivilLiability;
        proposalData.data = element;
      }

      tabs = [...tabs, { type: type, name: '', tabData: proposalData }];
      proposalData = {};
    }

    return tabs;
  }
}
```

And just to give an overview of the structure, to keep us sane:

```
<app-detail>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let idx = index">
    <app-civilliability-proposal-detail [model]="tab.tabData.data">
      <app-civilliability-step3 [(model)]="model" ></app-civilliability-step3>
      </app-civilliability-step3
    </app-civilliability-proposal-detail>
  </mat-tab
</app-detail>
```

**UPDATE 3:** Add tabs data:
[image]

Comment: `CivilLiabilityRequestType`'s `closed` property is readonly, hence it can't be assigned. Can you please show the model type?

Comment: Added the model. But I'm not sure if the property is a readonly here. I could be wrong ofc.

Comment: the error is pretty self-explanatory from that point of view: TypeError: Cannot assign to **read only property 'closed'** of object '[object Object]''. That means that whoever is creating the `CivilLiabilityRequestType` instance is setting that property to readonly. Where is it created?

Comment: It would be useful if you posted `civilliability-detail.component.ts` where the `model` is being changed in any way

Comment: Added more code that could help

Comment: Ok, could you please provide us with an example object from `tabs` array after calling `this.createTabsFromQuoteModel()`?

Comment: Added tabs result in update 3

Comment: `this.model.details` looks to be undefined or not-readable, I think there is nothing more to say

Comment: You should print `this.model.details` and try to access `closed`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe this happens because you cannot modify an object that is stored in the state (ngRx), you could try something like this instead:

```
sendProposal() {
  this.store.dispatch(new CloseProposal(Object.assign({}, this.model, {
    details: { closed: true }
  })));
}
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct solution, because this somehow solved the issue, on a different place. But you were right, you cant modify an object coming from the state.

Comment: I didn't know that NgRx state is read-only..... thanks for the help....

Comment: Genius!  thank you. Been struggling for a full day.

Comment: I ran into this same error recently, and it took me a minute to figure out that not only is it illegal to mutate an object I *get* from the ngrx store, but it is illegal also to continue mutating an object *after it's stored* to ngrx.

After passing the object to ngrx to store (the equivalent of your `this.model` here), I have to make a new local copy so as not to further mutate the object ngrx is holding as state.

Comment: "The number one rule of NgRx, immutability. This strictStateImmutability check verifies if a developer tries to modify the state object."
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictstateimmutability

You could turn it off, but then you should consider if that's really what you want. The example in the documentation can also be very helpful on defining a reducer for changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Object.assign method to change the value of the object as follows,

```
 Object.assign(target, source);
```

Answer (score 0):

For readonly data from state (ngRx), this is the only thing that worked for me --JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

```
this.providerLicenseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.userState.providerLicense))
```